# How to present contents in a book chapter and sections in a highly normalized repository

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

What is wrong with the below function, and how can I fix it.

```
  list() {
    return this.bookRepo.all().then(books =>
      Promise.all(books.map(book =>
        Promise.all([
          this.bookRepo.contents(book.id),
          this.bookRepo.chapters(book.id)
        ]).then(([contents, chapters]) =>
          Promise.all(chapters.map(chapter =>
            Promise.all([
              this.bookRepo.contents(chapter.id),
              this.bookRepo.sections(chapter.id)
            ]).then(([contents, sections]) =>
              Promise.all(sections.map(section =>
                this.bookRepo.contents(section.id).then(contents => [
                  section, contents
                ])))
                .then(sections => [chapter, contents, sections]))))
            .then(chapters => [book, contents, chapters])))));
  }
```

Problem is the return value of this function. I don't want to maintain it, write types for it, traverse it for rendering etc. It seems cumbersome, how can I abstract this or make it simpler?

This is my schema:

```
type BookId = string
type ChapterId = string
type SectionId = string
type ContentId = string

export type SourceId =
| ChapterId
| SectionId
| BookId

type Book = {
  id: BookId,
  name: string,
}

type Chapter = {
  id: ChapterId,
  bookId: BookId,
  name: string
}
type Section = {
  id: SectionId,
  chapterId: ChapterId,
  name: string
}

type Content = {
  id: ContentId,
  name: string,
  sourceId: SourceId,
  content: string
}
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Besides being tricky to read, what *is* wrong with it? What is it doing you don't want it to? What *should* it be doing based on your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: It's horrible and nobody would ever want to read or modify code written that way unless they like to torture themselves for a living.

The below is marginally more maintainable, principally through avoiding a christmas-tree of promises and giving things different names, although you'd have to get the types to align better with yours, and maybe hoist some of these loops steps into their own functions to finish the job.

```
type Id = string;

interface Entry {
  id: Id;
}

interface Doc {}

interface BookRepo {
  all: () => Promise<Array<Entry>>;
  sections: (id: Id) => Promise<Array<Entry>>;
  chapters: (id: Id) => Promise<Array<Entry>>;
  contents: (id: Id) => Promise<Doc>;
}

class Lister {
  constructor(readonly bookRepo: BookRepo) {}

  async list() {
    const { all, contents, sections, chapters } = this.bookRepo;
    const allBooks = await all();

    for (const bookRecord of allBooks) {
      const bookContents = await contents(bookRecord.id);
      const chapterRecords = await chapters(bookRecord.id);
      const bookChapters = await Promise.all(
        chapterRecords.map(async (chapterRecord) => {
          const chapterContents = await contents(chapterRecord.id);
          const chapterSectionRecords = await sections(chapterRecord.id);
          const chapterSections = await Promise.all(
            chapterSectionRecords.map(async (sectionRecord) => {
              const sectionContents = await contents(sectionRecord.id);
              return [sectionRecord, sectionContents];
            })
          );
          return [chapterRecord, chapterContents, chapterSections];
        })
      );
      return [bookRecord, bookContents, bookChapters];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is no different than original code, except the model types are wrong.